# How to get the highest accuracy of a model after the training

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, early-stopping

I have run a model with 4 epochs and using `early_stopping`.

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=2, restore_best_weights=True)
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=4, callbacks=[early_stopping])

Epoch 1/4
812/812 [==============================] - 68s 13ms/sample - loss: 0.6072 - acc: 0.717 - val_loss: 0.554 - val_acc: 0.7826
Epoch 2/4
812/812 [==============================] - 88s 11ms/sample - loss: 0.5650 - acc: 0.807 - val_loss: 0.527 - val_acc: 0.8157
Epoch 3/4
812/812 [==============================] - 88s 11ms/sample - loss: 0.5456 - acc: 0.830 - val_loss: 0.507 - val_acc: 0.8244
Epoch 4/4
812/812 [==============================] - 51s 9ms/sample - loss: 0.658 - acc: 0.833 - val_loss: 0.449 - val_acc: 0.8110
```

The highest `val_ac` corresponds to the third epoch, and is `0.8244`. However, the `accuracy_score` function will return the last val_acc value, which is `0.8110`.

```
yhat = model.predict_classes(testX)
accuracy = accuracy_score(testY, yhat)
```

It is possible to specify the epoch while calling the `predict_classes`in order to get the highest accuracy (in this case, the one corresponding to the third epoch) ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like early-stopping isn't being trigged because you're only training for 4 epochs and you've set early stopping to trigger when val_loss doesn't decrease over two epochs. If you look at your val_loss for each epoch, you can see it's still decreasing even on the fourth epoch.

So simply put, your model is just running the full four epochs without using early stopping, which is why it's using the weights learned in epoch 4 rather than the best in terms of `val_acc`.

To fix this, set `monitor='val_acc'` and run for a few more epochs. `val_acc` only starts to decrease after epoch 3, so earlystopping won't trigger until epoch 5 at the earliest.

Alternatively you could set `patience=1` so it only checks a single epoch ahead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ML_Engine . I run the model for many more epochs. I just took some to ask the question. I thing, what I needed was changing `monitor='val_loss'` to `monitor='val_acc'`. I will try with that.

Comment: Glad it helped! Would appreciate an 'accept' if I was able to help :)

Comment: I was testing it. `early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', mode='max', patience=4)///
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=25, verbose=1, batch_size=32, callbacks=[early_stopping])`. Unfortunately `accuracy_score(testY, yhat)` still returns the last `val_acc`.  Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: Can you post your training output again please? For each epoch

Comment: Sorry, I have already reset it. But it looks like the one I have provided in the question.

Comment: Is there any point at which the accuracy does not improve over 4 epochs? If not then it won't trigger early stopping. You could also try adding `min_delta` to be something like 0.01 which means it must increase by 1% over the number of epochs